# How to show a message (ex: No records found!) in the table when no records is returned?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using easyui datagrid in my application.How to show a message (ex: No records found!) in the table when no records is returned?

```
$('#test').datagrid({
onLoadSuccess:function(data){
    if(data.total == 0){
        alert("No Records founds");
    }

}

});
```

Comment: If you'll show us what you have tried we will help you to fix it.

Comment: So far i used alerts to show the message by checking the total count on onloadsuccess ,but now my requirement has changed.I got weired of how to add a new row dynamically.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: hi jay,i added my code...

Comment: Where is 'data' defined? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors.The data parameter comes by default on onloadsuccess event.If the total count is zero then I want to show the text in the grid instead of alert.

Answer (score 3):

I found some solution in jeasyui forum. Please refer the link below

http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=1881.msg4135#msg4135

Based on the link I made the below changes in my code

```
 $('#test').datagrid({

       onLoadSuccess:function(data){
           showGridMessage($('#test'));

       }
})

function showGridMessage(target){
       var opts = $(target).datagrid('options');
var vc = $(target).datagrid('getPanel').children('div.datagrid-view');
vc.children('div.datagrid-empty').remove();
if (!$(target).datagrid('getRows').length){
    var d = $('<div class="datagrid-empty"></div>').html('No Records Found').appendTo(vc);
    d.css({
        position:'absolute',
        left:0,
        top:50,
        width:'100%',
        textAlign:'center'
    });
}else{
      vc.children('div.datagrid-empty').remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is
while you select the data from database, you need to check if the result row is more than 0 or not
if it is more than 0 just parsing in an array with format `$sampledata[$i]['nameof_field1'] = $dataresult->column;`

if there is no data from the select, you need to parsing with the same format but an empty value `$sampledata[0]['nameof_field1'] = '';`

then you can try this code

```
onLoadSuccess:function(data){
  if(data.nameof_field1==''){
      alert("No Records founds");
  }

}
```